# Angularjs filter product by clicking catogery

Tags: angularjs

can you please give me code for filter products clicking on category menu. Below the codes HTML, JSON and JS.

Category HTML:

```
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="cat in allData"><a ng-click="catFun(cat.catogery)" class="list-group-item">{{cat.catogery}}</a></li>
```

Product display HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="product in allData | filter:filterBycat" class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
 <div class="thumbnail">
  <img ng-src="{{product.productImg}}" alt="">
      <div class="caption">
           <h4 class="pull-right">{{product.productPrice}}</h4>
           <h4><a ng-href="#/productdetails/{{product.id}}">{{product.productTitle}}</a></h4>
          <p>{{product.description}}</p>
       </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

JSON data:

```
"1": {
    "id":"1",
    "catogery":"men",
    "productImg": "http://placehold.it/320x150",
    "description": "This is a short description. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
    "productTitle": "First Product",
    "productPrice": "24.99",
},
"2": {
    "id":"2",
    "catogery":"women",
    "productImg": "http://placehold.it/320x150",
    "description": "This is a short description. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
    "productTitle": "Second Product",
    "productPrice": "26.99",
},
```

JS Code:

```
$scope.filtered = {};
$scope.catFun = function(catVal){
    $scope.filtered = catVal;
};

$scope.filterBycat = function(item){
    if($scope.filtered){
        return $scope.filtered === Object;
    }else{
        return item;
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you adding a sample on https://codepen.io/, please?

Comment: @tarun-mishra: can you please make your question more specific? What is your issue? What is not working currently in your code? What did you try?
 What do you struggle to understand?

Comment: @ThomasGuillory please check project over code pen it's large project so i added small part. i am getting data using services by json you can seen in angularjs service 

https://codepen.io/tarunmishra592/pen/ZKZLjV?editors=1010

Comment: @ThomasGuillory i want filter products clicking on category menu accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Replace filterByCat with following function

```
  $scope.getFilter = function(){
    return {"catogery":$scope.filtered}
  }
```

and in the view:

```
<div ng-repeat="product in allData | filter:getFilter"> ... </dive>
```

Here is a sample code on [codepen.com](https://codepen.io/mostafa-barmshory/pen/NjJVPP)

Comment: Hi @مصطفی Please check i have added project over codepen i getting data by services that i have created you can see in js.

Using your code i am getting error like:

Expected array but received: {"1":{"id":"1","catogery":"men"}}

Answer (score 0):

Angular filters are expecting an array as input. Your data is not an array, but an object. Before being able to use the filter, you first need to correctly format your data.

If you don't care about the keys content, you can use the following:

```
$scope.allData = Object.keys(d).map(function(key){ return d[key] })
```

Here is a modified version of your pen examplifying this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OmYmGJ